# How can I get dynamic control over the domain of a contour plot?

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I am trying to plot a specified contour of my function of two variables.

I call `ContourPlot` with my function as follows:

```
MyFunc[f_, x_, y_] := 
  toplot = f;
  k = x*y;
  ContourPlot[{toplot == k}, {x1, 0, 100}, {x2, 0, 100}]
```

I need to set the domain dynamically, because when I have high value of `k`, the contour could be outside the statically specified domain.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: what is `x,y` and `x1,x2` ? are they related? Are you looking for something like this `Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[{x y == k}, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}], {k, 0, 1000}]`

Comment: but: 1) I need to do this without using Manipulate and 2) I need to plot **toplot** not **xy**

Comment: Why can't you use `Manipulate`?

Comment: Then try `ContourPlot3D` like `toplot = f; k = x y; ContourPlot3D[
 toplot == k, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {f, 0, 100}]`

Comment: I can't use manipulate because i've fixed value and it isn't my goal show all possible value of k.
And i need also 2D Plot. So, ContourPlot3D is not solution.